# Missing aps-environment in provisioning profile!

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

For some reason our adhoc provisioning profile just won't have the aps-environment entitlement! We've made sure that **the profile is generated after we enabled the production apns** for that app id. We've actually even created a new adhoc profile for that app id and **even the new profile does not have that entitlement** when checked using a text editor. What's going on?

Comment: Weird. Where did you get this **Missing aps-environment in provisioning profile!** error, the Xcode compiler result?

Comment: It's an error generated on build if the profile used to sign doesn't have the push entitlements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Ensure the Bundle Identifier matches the one in your project's plist.
2. Create a new App ID, and configure it for production/development push *before* creating a new provisioning profile.
3. Make sure you're build and archiving on the right target, with the right configuration. You might need to go back to project settings and double check with the correct configuration selected (I use release for this).

Comment: Started to work when I created new Provisioning Profile for existing AppID. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If the entitlement is still missing after *regenerating that profile* and/or making a new one, it sounds like a bug in the iOS Portal site (server side).

Contact [Developer Programs](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) to request their help or explanation (doesn't count toward your DTS TSI's). Use the "Program Benefits" link on that page, as it is "for questions about creating provisioning profiles..."
For others, note that once an App ID has new entitlement settings (such as happens when you enable Push Notification for that App ID) you must then manually regenerate all associated profiles to get the new entitlements onto the profile. Do that on the iOS Portal site [Provisioning](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action) sidebar, "Development" or "Distribution" tab (as appropriate). Go into each profile and regenerate them by clicking "Modify" or "Edit". On the edit page, something needs to change to enable the "Submit" button, so, for a Distribution Provisioning Profile, temporarily switch the distribution method from "App Store" to "Ad Hoc" and then back. Then click Submit to update the profile.

Comment: Thank you very much. This fixed the issue for me:

`temporarily switch the distribution method from "App Store" to "Ad Hoc" and then back`

Comment: I had the exact same problem. I think the new iOS provisioning portal doesn't have the bug any more. Also - the generate/save button is enabled right from the start now when you edit an existing profile, no need to change to adhoc and back..

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure your local entitlements file doesn't include extra keys, e.g. aps-environment.**

There is not a bug on the Apple Portal. I fixed this issue on my end, by removing the aps-environment key from my local entitlements file. Apparently, Xcode does a preliminary check by comparing your entitlements files with your installed provisioning profiles. If it sees anything in your entitlements file that is not included in your profile, then the action it lists in the compile error is to add the missing entitlement to the profile. However, what it really should say instead is to ensure that your entitlements file matches your profile.

Therefore, this appears to be a bug in the Xcode's profile verification process.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it for me - wanted to add a comment to add visibility to this as I have spent hours on this!